# How to say Hello World from a shared node.js server

Tags: coldfusion

Hello my fellow ColdFusion developers!

I'm trying to learn node.js, and I have a free sandbox account at http://pusher.com/.
If I view the API access, they give pastable html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Pusher Test</title>
  <script src="http://js.pusherapp.com/1.9/pusher.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.log = function(message) {
      if (window.console && window.console.log) window.console.log(message);
    };

    // Flash fallback logging - don't include this in production
    WEB_SOCKET_DEBUG = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher('0xxxx0xxxxxxxxxxxx00');
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
    channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {
      alert(data);
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

and I have pasted that into a web page.

Then they give some code to send via curl:

```
curl -d "hello world" \
"http://api.pusherapp.com/apps/7499/channels/test_channel/events?"\
"name=my_event&"\
"body_md5=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&"\
"auth_version=1.0&"\
"auth_key=0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx00&"\
"auth_timestamp=1318305150&"\
"auth_signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

but I don't think I have curl.

Q: Can I use cfhttp instead?

Comment: Yes, in short. Why use CF though, thought you are wanting to work with node? Unless of course you are running node on Windows :$

Comment: Well, I'm still trying to get Hello World to work, so I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong (like using ColdFusion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what is going on here. NodeJS is not your web browser. I do not see how NodeJS relates to any of this.

I never used pusher or coldfusion before, but I am sure you can use ColdFusion to send simple HTTP requests to "pusher", just like curl. HTTP requests are not complicated at all, and curl is a simple command line program that sends and receives them.

The curl command is just opening that long URL as POST request, and sending "hello world" as the body, and "hello world" should appear in your web browser.

Comment: I just don't get it.  I teach in a classroom filled with computers, and I'd like to have an interactive experience for my students where everyone is updating all the time (events).  I'm just trying to follow the directions to get Hello World to work.  Yep, I am a Windows person.

Comment: Ah! Very interesting. Try http://socket.io/. You could have one master server and make all the students include the socket.io in the browser, and have each person implement their own chat system with a chat protocol you define. I do not imagine should take much. If you are looking for some help, send me an e-mail/message. I will be happy to give some pointers.